# Overflow auto in table _td_ that has no certain height

Tags: html, css

I have a table with fixed height in which one row has fixed height and another gets height left and I need to get scrollbar in the flexible row when its inner content is high.
Is it possible to do?

```
<table style="width: 50%; height: 300px; overflow:auto">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 50px;background:grey"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="overflow:auto">
    <td style="background:yellow; overflow:auto">
                <script>
                    for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
                        document.write(i + " Sample text<br>");
                    }
                </script>
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

UPD: Changed the code to be more explicit. I need overflow:auto on my yellow block.
After inserting a lot of content table height exceeds 300px

Answer (score 3):

#### [See Working Example](http://jsbin.com/iqihu3)

---

Putting a `div` inside your flexible `td` and settings its `overflow` property should do the trick:

```
<table style="width: 50%; height: 300px; overflow:auto">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 50px;background:grey"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="overflow:auto">
    <td style="background:yellow;">
        <div style="height: 500px; overflow:auto; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;">
          high content
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: <table style="width: 50%; height: 300px; overflow:auto">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 50px;background:grey"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="overflow:auto">
    <td style="background:yellow; overflow: auto">
        <div style="overflow: auto">
                    <script>
                        for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
                            document.write(i + " Sample text<br>");
                        }
                    </script>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>

Comment: It doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: @noxvile: The code you pasted in your comment is not what I have posted in my answer :)

Comment: plz check out update in question description. I've made it to clarify problem I have

Comment: never put overflow:auto into another overflow:auto, as this might leave you with two scrollbars near each other.

Comment: @Sarfraz : it works neither in FireFox nor Chrome : the table isn't limited to 300px height. If we add a "Hello" before the table, it shouldn't scroll but is does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution : put a div inside the TD, and delete the others "`overflow:auto`".

```
<table style="width: 50%; height: 300px; ">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 50px;background:grey"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td style="background:yellow;">
        <div style="overflow:auto;height:100%;">
                <script>
                    for (i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
                        document.write(i + " Sample text<br>");
                    }
                </script>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

EDIT : I saw a problem: it works only on CHROME, not on FIREFOX!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf9LcsoL/)